# Unable to run the oozie coordinator xml file

Tags: xml, hadoop, bigdata

I am practicing hands-on lab on bigdata university website and there they show that how to run oozie coordinator, I have followed the same instruction, but I am getting the following error and not able to figure out any solution for the same, any help will be appreciated.

biadmin@bivm:/opt/ibm/biginsights/oozie/bin> ./oozie job -run -config ~/coord/coordinator.properties

```html
Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Workflow'. One of '{"uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1":workflow}' is expected.
```

I am using below coordinator.xml  and coordinator.properties:

********* coordinator.xml ******************

```html
<coordinator-app name="Schedule_WordCount" frequency="${freq}" 

start="${startTime}" end="${endTime}" timezone="${timezone}" 

xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1"> 

 <action> 

 <workflow> 

 <app-path>${workflowPath}</app-path> 

 <configuration> 

 <property> 

 <name>queueName</name> 

 <value>default</value> 

 </property> 

 </configuration> 

 </workflow> 

 </action> 

</coordinator-app>
```

************************* coordinator.properties***********

```html
oozie.coord.application.path=hdfs://bivm:9000/user/biadmin/coord

freq=1440

startTime=2014-10-12T14:00Z (Set this to a date in the future)

endTime=2014-10-13T14:00Z (Set this to a date in the future)

timezone=UTC

workflowPath=hdfs://bivm:9000/user/biadmin/oozieWF

jobtracker=bivm:9001

namenode=bivm:9000

PREFIX=hdfs://bivm:9000/user
```

Comment: coordinator.xml is copied on to hdfs? make sure the one in your hdfs is valid.

Comment: Yes, I have copied the coordinator.xml on to hdfs. and when, I chech the file in hdfs, its the same.

Comment: It looks like its not able to understand the workflow tag, where as its expecting a workflow tag from the uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1. Try adding a prefix for the namespace. Ideally it should work without prefix.